# Where can I find the admin code for uploading an image in django?

Tags: python, django, image, file, file-upload

I'm currently coding an image upload in a view and I want to compare it to the code the admin uses for uploading images. Is there code the admin generates the file forms from?  **Where can I find the python code to an admin image/file upload?**

I'm using ubuntu 14, python 2.7 and django 1.9.

I have been searching around in here for the admin code for uploading files, but I cannot find it:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/
```

This is my image upload code in my view I want to compare to the admin image upload code:

```
                avatarFile=request.FILES["avatar_im"]
                print(avatarFile)
                for key, file in request.FILES.items():
                    path = file.name
                    path = "images/"+path
                    dest = open(path, 'w')
                    if file.multiple_chunks:
                        for a in file.chunks():
                            dest.write(a)
                    else:
                        dest.write(file.read())
                    dest.close()
```

I'm trying to understand how my admin uploads files to my 
*MEDIA_ROOT/images*, and why my code uploads to my *PROJECT_ROOT/images* folder.

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_pro/media')
```

Comment: search in `django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage`

Comment: ... and to update to MEDIA_ROOT just use `path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'images', file.name)`

Comment: Source codes for the /admin/ site is here: https://github.com/django/django/tree/53ccffdb8c8e47a4d4304df453d8c79a9be295ab/django/contrib/admin, where you can start search the codes (I don't where is it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code used for file uploading stays inside

`django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage`

and

`django.core.files.move`

If you want to upload files in the directory `MEDIA_ROOT/images/` then just use:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
...
...
path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'images', file.name)
```

Comment: This works. One other question... How do I access the attribute `upload_to` ? From what I read it sets the path.

Comment: If you mean getting the upload_to arg set when defining the model field, just `mymodel.myfilefield.field.upload_to`. Fell free to accept the answer if was useful to you